# How can I display an inline bibentry without it being added to the bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, citing, bibentry

I'm doing some corrections on my thesis at the moment, and I have to remove an accidental citation to myself in my bibliography.
I have a page at the start where I have to list publications that became part of the thesis.

I was wondering if there's a way to include a bibentry without it appearing in my bibliography.

Below is the code for the chapter:

```
\chapter*{Publications}

The work in this thesis has contributed to the following publication:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \bibentry{keyToPaper}
\end{itemize}
```

I'm using `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` and in my front matter I have:

```
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*
```

Otherwise I'm just using standard bibtex, the above package and command were just included for this page.